# Set graphics views coordinate system centered bottom-left instead of top-left

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qgraphicsview

I have created a Graphicsview and noticed that the coordinate system looks like this:

```
(0,0) (1,1) - - - - - - - (n,n)
(1,1)
  |
  |
  |
  |
(n,n)
```

However, what I would like to have is the following system:

```
(n,n)
  |
  |
  |
  |
(1,1)
(0,0) (1,1) - - - - - - - (n,n)
```

Is it possible to shift the coordinate system to be like this in a neat way?

Comment: You may wan't to consider leaving it as is, having a top left origin is commonly used for images. If you want to also read the position relative to the bottom left you can calculate it as `image_height - y_coord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I figured this one out!

Using self.scale(1, -1) will mirror the graphicsview around the y-axis.

Similarly, using self.scale(-1, 1) would mirror the graphicsview around the x-axis.